# how to Convert List<String> to List<File>

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to convert a list string into list file in flutter in this manner:

```
 _listaImagens = _var.photo.cast<File>();

* _var.photo is a images return the firebase db.

*  _listaImagens is a List<File> 

List<File> _listaImagens = List();
```

but this yield an error, below:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
List<String> strings = ["test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt"];

List<File> out = [];  

strings.forEach((i){
  out.add(File(i));
});
```

Comment: this is a flutter's way: `strings.map((s) => File(s))` - it gives `Iterable` though - if a `List` is really needed you may call `toList()` method on it

Answer (score 0):

This solution is partial works for me: `List<String> strings = _var.photo; List<File> files = []; strings.forEach((i){ setState(() { files.add( File(i) ); }); }); print(_listaImagens); print(files);` `_listaImagens.addAll(files)` however, when displaying the image, it is blank. the format I have does not seem to be different ... when I insert a photo File imagemSelecionada = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

[image]